# Strange menu behaviour wordpress admin

Tags: menus, admin

I am able to get logged into my site, but when I hover over some of the menu options, the links behave in an odd manner and some of the link text disappears etc, some of them sit on top of each other:

[image]

Has anybody got any guidance on what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with [google chrome](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/33199), i think the devs are working on a core fix but in the mean time you can add this to your functions.php and it should do the trick:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'chrome_fix' );

function chrome_fix() {

    if ( strpos( $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_USER_AGENT' ], 'Chrome' ) !== false ) {
        wp_add_inline_style( 'wp-admin', '#adminmenu { transform: translateZ(0) }' );
    }
}
```